# Migrate add-on domain olddomain.com to newdomain.com

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, webserver, nameserver

I have 2 domains that are registered at GoDaddy :

```
domaina.com (not hosted, only domain name is registered to GD)
domainb.com (hosted at a different webhost, domain name registered to GD)
```

`domainb.com` is an already working site, with a different webhost, but the domain name is registered to GoDaddy (and I assume the nameservers are changed to redirect to the webhost).

Now, I don't understand why this was done, but `domainb.com` is considered a subdomain on the host... meaning the files are in a seperate folder on the server.
Ex : `public-html/domainb.com/public-html/FILES`

The structure is similar to this on the webhost:

```
HostNAME (main root folder)
    domainb.com (subdomain of hostname)
    domainc.com (etc...)
    domaind.com (etc...)
```

I want to transfer the site `domainb.com` to `domaina.com`, meaning `domaina.com` will become the new website, without having to re-upload all the content and CMS. The old one will redirect to `domaina.com` once the transfer is done (using 301 redirects).

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the web server configuration, e.g. *httpd.conf*, you can just edit the existing `domaina.com` VirtualHost or create a new one using the `domainb.com` directory as its root. So if the absolute path to the files for `domainb.com` is `/var/www/public-html/domainb.com/public-html`, and you want to host it as `domaina.com`:

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@domaina.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/public-html/domainb.com/public-html
ServerName www.domaina.com
ErrorLog logs/domaina.com-error_log
TransferLog logs/domaina.com-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cpanel, just use the option Modify and Account and your old domain will be changed into the new one.Thus, the old domain will be deleted from the server and the file will remain.

You will only have to check the db connection after this and check the paths for your scripts ( as they may change as a result of the domain changing).